# Redraw DataTemplate of ContentControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contentcontrol

I have the following `ContentControl`:

```
<ContentControl 
    Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=SelectedEntry}">
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="controls:HCITextListEntry">
            <controls:MyCustomControl
                Text="{Binding Text}" 
                Parameter="{Binding Parameters}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

Everytime the `SelectedEntry` property changes, I want to redraw/reinit `MyCustomControl`. Actually only the properties are updated.

Comment: Do whatever necessary in a PropertyChangedCallback of one of the control's bound properties.

Comment: Normally I do so, but in this case I need to construct a new instance

Comment: You may drop the ContentTemplate and write a converter for the Content Binding that returns a MyCustomControl instance.

Comment: Never thought of binding an instance of a `Control` to the `Content` property! What a great idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may drop the ContentTemplate and write a converter for the Content Binding that returns a MyCustomControl instance:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedEntry,
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                          Converter={StaticResource MyCustomControlConverter}}"/>
```

The converter:

```
public class MyCustomControlConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var control = new MyCustomControl();

        control.SetBinding(MyCustomControl.TextProperty,
            new Binding("Text") { Source = value });
        control.SetBinding(MyCustomControl.ParameterProperty,
            new Binding("Parameters") { Source = value });

        return control;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```